# Java regex phone number

Tags: java, regex, phone-number

I am supplying the following regex : ^((?:\+27|27)|0)(\d{9})$
for number of South Africa and want to only return true for numbers that start with +27 or 27 or 0. eg; +27832227765, 27838776654 or 0612323434.

I tried using:
[regexplanet.com](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

and [regex test](http://regex-testdrive.com/en/dotest)

But both return false no matter what I enter (even simple regex).

Anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you just check the regex in the online tester or in code? In Java code, `^(\\+?27|0)(\\d{9})$` should work. In a tester, `^(\+?27|0)(\d{9})$` should work.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Good answer

Comment: I posted my answer, please check.

Answer (score 3):

In Java code, you need to double the backslashes, and in a online tester, the backslashes must be single.

Also, it is not necessary to use start and end of string markers if used with `String#matches` as this method requires a full string match.

Here is how your Java code can look like:

```
String rex = "(\\+?27|0)(\\d{9})";
System.out.println("+27832227765".matches(rex)); // => true
System.out.println("27838776654".matches(rex));  // => true
System.out.println("0612323434".matches(rex));   // => true
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/C8ERIH)

If you use `String#find`, you will need the `^` and `$` anchors you have in the original regex.

Note I shortened `((?:\+27|27)|0)` to `(\+?27|0)` as `?` quantifier means *1 or 0 occurrences*. The extra grouping is really redundant here. Also, If you are not using captured texts, I'd suggest turning the first group into a non-capturing (i.e. `(?:\+?27|0)`) and remove the round brackets from `\d{9}`:

```
String rex = "(?:\\+?27|0)\\d{9}";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an expression tested on http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/# for numbers that start with +27 or 27 or 0 and after with length 9.

```
^((0)|(27)|(\+27))(\d{9})$
```

It's ok with your numbers :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work, here is a [variant](https://regex101.com/r/zN0sS1/1).  (I removed ^ and $ for this example):

```
((?:\+27|27|0)(?:\d{9}))
```