# Create regex for telephone numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I would like to create a regex validation check for the following phone numbers in javascript:

**+26481**3654562

**+26481**5689245

**+26485**3654562

**+26485**5689245

**+26461**253425

**+26461**598756

**081**1265984

**085**1265984

**061**653265

> Note: the part that are bold must be there. the numbers thereafter are accepted. the numbers starting with +26461 and 061 must have one number less compared to +26481 or +24685 and 081 or 085.

Current effort: `/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/`

Comment: @RubensFarias wow, that's creepy :) asking exact same question

Comment: @Dieterg wow, that's creepy :) asking exact same question

Comment: /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/

Comment: this is my first time using regex

Comment: What do you mean "the parts that are bold must be there"? You've asked for a regex that matches nine *specific* phone numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java regex phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477950/java-regex-phone-number)

Comment: idk, what about just matching those numbers then

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
^(\+26461(\d{6})|\+2648(\d{8})|08(1|5)(\d{7})|061(\d{6}))$
```

+26461(\d{6}) 1st group for 26461

+2648(\d{8} 2nd group for 2648

08(1|5)(\d{7}) 3rd group for 081 or 085

061(\d{6}) last group for 061